# Is it possible to spawn big amount of processes in SimGrid?

Tags: simgrid

I have master process which spawns 50000 processes

```
int master(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    string name = tostring(i);
    MSG_process_create(name.c_str(), some_code, NULL, MSG_host_self());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But when I run this code I have an error:

```
[0.000000] /home/ubuntu/Downloads/simgrid/src/simix/smx_context.cpp:187: [xbt/CRITICAL] Failed to protect stack: Cannot allocate memory
```

How can I overcome it or it is impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://simgrid.gforge.inria.fr/simgrid/3.13.90/doc/options.html#options_virt:

*If you want to push the scalability limits of your code, you might want to
reduce the contexts/stack-size item. Its default value is 8192 (in KiB),
while our Chord simulation works with stacks as small as 16 KiB, for
example.*

Also, you want to make sure (with valgrind) that your application does not leak memory because that's what you need the most to scale in amount of processes.